# handle onchangeview event for Bing maps

Tags: event-handling, bing-maps

I'm trying to handle the onchangeview event for bing maps

In the js intialize method I have the following code:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapviewer"), {
    credentials: bingMapsKey, 
    center : new Microsoft.Maps.Location(42.3508, -71.0717),
    zoom: 12
    });
//Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "onchangeview", handleChangeView);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "onclick", handleChangeView);
mapviewer.attachEvent("onchangeview", handleChangeView);
```

I also have this function

function handleChangeView(e) {

}

this function is never called, and I am not sure why as the handler is set up properly.

I also don't understand the difference between the following 2 lines and when I should attach an event one way or the other

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "onclick", handleChangeView);
mapviewer.attachEvent("onchangeview", handleChangeView);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Many events were renamed in 7, I think you want to use "**click**" instead of "*onclick*" and "**viewchangeend**" instead of "*onchangeview*".

Depending on what you need it for, you may prefer events "**viewchangestart**", "**viewchange**" or "**targetviewchanged**" however.

---

Also, you should definitely use "**Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler**" to setup the listeners with 7, all events use the Events object now.

---

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 350px;"></div>   


<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * Map click event handler.
 */
function onclick(e){
    var map = this.target; //reference to the Map object from which it came
    //...
    var x = e.getX(); // horizontal position of the click
    var y = e.getY(); // vertical position of the click
    //...
    console.log('The map has been clicked');
}

/**
 * View change event handler.
 */
function onview(){
    var map = this.target; //reference to the Map object from which it came
    //...
    console.log('The view has changed');
}

/**
 * Load the map and setup event listeners
 */
function init(){
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"),
        {
            credentials: "YOUR-BING-KEY",
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
        }
    );
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "click", onclick);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "viewchangeend", onview);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

List of events (at the bottom of the page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the new event at the same time that you add it:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "click", function(args) {
    ...
});
```

The value of `args` will be dependent on the object and the event you're using. In this case it's a MouseEventArgs object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406731.aspx).